# What is the difference between disturbance and noise for dynamic systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, noise, kalman-filter

In most references from dynamic system theory, the following linear continuous dynamic system is considered.
$$\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)+Dd_{1}(t)\quad (1)$$
$$y(t)=Cx(t)+Ed_{2}(t) \quad (2)$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, y\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{p}},d_{1}\in
{{\mathbb{R}}^{m}},d_{2}\in{{\mathbb{R}}^{q}}$  represent the state vector, measurement output vector, process disturbance and  measurement disturbance vector respectively.  $A, B, C, D, E$ are constants matrices of appropriate dimension.

Again, the following linear discrete dynamic system is mostly studied in references.
$$x(k+1)=Ax(k)+Bu(k)+Dw_{1}(k)\quad (3)$$
$$y(k)=Cx(k)+Ew_{2}(k)\quad (4)$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, y\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{p}},w_{1}\in
{{\mathbb{R}}^{m}},w_{2}\in{{\mathbb{R}}^{q}}$  represent the state vector, measurement output vector, process noise and  measurement noise vector respectively.

The questions are stated as following.

1) Are the disturbance $d$ and noise $w$ the same thing? If not, why in continuous system, only disturbance is considered, and only noise is considered in discrete system?

2) In the continuous system, when the disturbance $d$ is stated as a certain function, can the disturbance $d$  be assumed to be differential?  Is this assumption reasonable?

3) In the continuous system, when the disturbance $d$ can be stated as a stochastic process such as Gauss white noise, can the disturbance $d$  be assumed to be differential? Is this assumption reasonable?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140346/what-is-the-difference-between-disturbance-and-noise-for-dynamic-systems

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, same thing, mutatis mutandis.

2 - Reasonable to assume $d$ differentiable, or at least continuous piecewise. But it's also reasonable to think of $d$ as a stochastic process, in which case the math becomes more complicated. Start with the simpler cases, and then proceed to more general models as needed.

3 - No, a Wiener process, of which white noise is a generalized derivative, is nowhere differentiable. Go into these more complex models if needed; otherwise stick with the more restrictive assumptions which make everything easier.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind help. Could you state more details for the reasonability to assume $d$ differentiable? Thanks again.

Comment: "Noise" or disturbances are what we can't model or know a priori. An arbitrary function can be approximated by a smooth function as precisely as one wishes. 

The system under consideration is linear, therefore it has a finite gain in finite time. A bounded perturbation will cause a bounded change in the output, and the effects of perturbations is additive. Thus if we do not know much about $d$ we may start with the simpler case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful comment. I learn a lot  from your answer. Furthermore, when we consider nonlinear systems such as Lipschitz nonlinear systems, can we still assume $d$ differentiable? Finally, what is the situation for general nonlinear systems? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'd keep the simpler assumptions, unless I had strong reasons to think that the model is insufficient for a given application. The fact that the differential equations are not linear doesn't compel us to make things even more difficult.....